# ¿Cómo recuperar los datos de un procedimiento almacenado al hacer clic en un botón con asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Estoy intentando crear un portal web con ASP.Net y MVC que permita al usuario ingresar un nombre (o parte de él) en un cuadro de texto y al hacer clic en el botón "Buscar", ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server que se encarga de buscar ese nombre en distintas tablas, de distintas bases de datos, de modo que al terminar la ejecución muestre el resultado en una tabla.

Con WebForm es muy sencillo, pues creo una clase que ejecute el procedimiento, en el código del botón escribo el código para obtener el valor ingresado en el TextBox y dependiendo de si hay o no coincidencias muestro un DataGridView, pero el asunto es que MVC funciona diferente y no se como realizar esta tarea con esta tecnología, pues con MVC y Entity Framework se utilizan consultas de LINQ contra modelos de Entity Framework, que no es mi caso.

De antemano, gracias por su tiempo. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Esto hago en el código del botón (usando WebForm):

```
var _varPers = new Personas();
var _varResult = _varPers.Buscar(inputvalue.Text);

if (_varResult.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataGrid1.DataSource = _varResult;
    DataGrid1.DataBind();
    DataGrid1.Visible = true;
    lblcount.Text = string.Concat(_varResult.Rows.Count.ToString(), " coincidencias.");
}
else
{
    DataGrid1.DataSource = null;
    DataGrid1.Visible = false;
    lblcount.Text = "Ninguna coincidencia encontrada.";
}
```

Comment: Si el stored retorna un result set con las filas que quieres entonces vas a diseño, agregar función y configuras para retorne una Entity. En MVC usamos una clase para el Model y otra para el ViewModel porque no siempre se va a mostrar todo en la view. Por ejemplo en una página para cambiar password de usuario el ViewModel tiene dos passwords para validar que sean iguales, pero el Model tiene uno solo porque es lo que hay en la BD.

Comment: Si lo pudiste en ASP.NET no entiendo cual es tu problema en hacerlo en ASP.NET MVC, podrías [edit] tu pregunta e incluir la manera como lo haces en ASP.NET y el cómo lo quieres en ASP.NET MVC. Recuerda que este sitio no es de plantear tutoriales, sino de resolver problemas específicos. Asimismo, indicar la manera como quieres invocar el procedimiento almacenado, por ADO.NET u otro.

Comment: Hice cambios al formular mi problema. Saludos.